# Active Records order by ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, ruby-on-rails-4

If I have records with ids: 1,2,3,4 and want sort them a certain way, like this 1, 4, 2, 3, how can I do this?

I think something like that, but it doesn't work of course.

```
Service.all.order(id: [1, 4, 2, 3])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Justin Weiss wrote a [blog article about this problem](http://www.justinweiss.com/blog/2015/04/20/how-to-select-database-records-in-an-arbitrary-order/) just two days ago.

It seems to be a good approach to tell the database about the preferred order and load all records sorted in that order directly from the database. Example from his [blog article](http://www.justinweiss.com/blog/2015/04/20/how-to-select-database-records-in-an-arbitrary-order/).

Add the following extension to your application:

```
# e.g. in config/initializers/find_by_ordered_ids.rb
module FindByOrderedIdsActiveRecordExtension
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  module ClassMethods
    def find_ordered(ids)
      order_clause = "CASE id "
      ids.each_with_index do |id, index|
        order_clause << "WHEN #{id} THEN #{index} "
      end
      order_clause << "ELSE #{ids.length} END"
      where(id: ids).order(order_clause)
    end
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Base.include(FindByOrderedIdsActiveRecordExtension)
```

That would allow you to write queries like this:

```
Service.find_ordered([2, 1, 3]) # => [2, 1, 3]
```

Comment: Hm, now ```find_by_ordered_ids.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Extensions (NameError)```

Comment: @VitalyFry : I removed the namespaces from the original example. Please try again.

Comment: I recommend you replace `order_clause = "CASE id "` with `order_clause = "CASE #{self.table_name}.id "`. This will prevent any ambiguous queries when using Joins and whatnot.

Answer (score 0):

```
 order = [1,4,2,3]
 @services = []
   order.each do |id|
   @services << Services.find(id)
   end
```

Comment: This is very inefficient, because it would make N (size of the array) queries to the database instead of just one.

Comment: Totally agree. The OP did not mention if they cared how many queries would take place or if they were ever going to do more than the 4 used in their example.