# rails controller custom text order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a model `Post` with columns `body` and `status`.

```
# Post.rb:
STATUSES = ["Active", "Frozen", "Finished"]

# Posts_controller:
`@posts = Post.order('status DESC')`
```

How can I make the order not alphabetical, but custom?

Like:

```
@posts = Post.order('status Finished, Active, Frozen')
```

Comment: Databases do not support custom order out of the box, but something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/29785879/2483313 (without the where condition and scoped to the status column) might work for you.

Comment: Look into using an [`enum`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html#method-i-enum) for the status where the values are stored as integers in the database. Assuming you only want a fixed order, rather than customising per query you'd be able to order the options in the enum tor match the desired order.

Answer (score 1):

A commenter suggested using `enum`, and that may be best for you. You can also try adding a function at the database level that let's you do custom sorts, depending on your database. Here's a [quick blog post](https://www.gab.lc/articles/order_by_custom_list/) on how you might set that up. Your sort function might look something like this (credit to blog post cited above):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION custom_sort(anyarray, anyelement)
  RETURNS INT AS 
$$
  SELECT i FROM (
     SELECT generate_series(array_lower($1,1),array_upper($1,1))
  ) g(i)
  WHERE $1[i] = $2
  LIMIT 1;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;
```

This gives you a function you can call with a custom ordering, so your sort might look like this:

```
ORDER BY custom_sort (ARRAY['Finished', 'Active', 'Frozen'], posts.status)
```